# Check if filesystem is mounted on remote server in bash script

Tags: bash

I have many linux servers, I want to check if filesystem is mount let say on /data , if it is mounted I want get filesystem size,used..extra with df command, but the issue I could not check if it is mounted or no

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in ($cat list_of_hosts.txt); do echo $i; ssh -q $i mount | grep '/data'; done
```

**Explanation**

The above one liner will iterate through each of the hosts in "list_of_hosts.txt" (put each new host on a new line). It will output the name of the server and then ssh to it and print out a list of it's mounts. It will filter the list of mounts and return only those mounts matching the pattern between the '' characters.